# Is there a message size restriction on gmail actions?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I wanted to add a convenient google actions link to an internal email we send (from: the same email address as the to: email same address). However, in the course of debugging it I realized the link only shows up for the shorter diagnostics messages.

Is there anything in the gmail actions code that requires the message to be a certain length or less in order for the action link to render?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, There is no limitation on the length of the message for the "[Go-to](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action)" action link. It helps users to go to your site which can be website/page/anything to complete the action.